# Why aren't my Fusion Table Layers and Styles working?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am currently using a Google Maps Fusion Table for County information to display the county boundaries for Texas.  There are over 200+ counties in Texas. I am looping through an array of values for each county and need to color-code the county based on the value in the array.  There are 4 levels of colors for the county: `Stop`, `Warning`, `Watch` and `Open`.  Everything seems to be working, except that the color is only being applied to 5 counties.  The limit of styles is 5 and the limit of layers is also 5, but I am only using 1 layer and 4 styles.

Can someone tell me what I am dong wrong?  Or is this just not possible via the API?

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
var styles = new Array();
var ftLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();

function loadTexas() {
    loadFusionLayer('TX');
    ftLayer.setMap(map);
    for (var i = 0; i < aryCounty.length; i++) {
        styleLayer("'State Abbr.' = 'TX' AND 'County Name' = '" +
            aryCounty[i].County + "'", 1000);
    }
    ftLayer.set('styles', styles);
}

function loadFusionLayer(state) {    
    if (state != null) {
        where = "'State Abbr.' IN ('" + state + "')";
    }
    var select = "geometry, 'State Abbr.', 'County Name'";
    ftLayer.setOptions({          
        query: {            
            select: select,            
            from: countyTableId,            
            where: where
        }  
    });        
} 

function styleLayer(where, actualValue) {
    var color = setPolygonColorBy(actualValue);
    styles.push({                        
        where: where,                  
        polygonOptions: {                              
            fillColor: color,            
            fillOpacity: 0.6           
        }          
    });         
}

function setPolygonColorBy(actualValue, divisor) { 
    var status;
    var stop = STATUS_LAYER_STYLES["Stop"].color;
    var warning = STATUS_LAYER_STYLES["Warning"].color;
    var watch = STATUS_LAYER_STYLES["Watch"].color;
    var open = STATUS_LAYER_STYLES["Open"].color;
    if (actualValue >= minValue && actualValue < midValue) {
        status = watch;
    }
    else if (actualValue >=midValue && actualValue < maxValue) {
        status = warning;
    }
    else if (actualValue >= maxValue) {
        status = stop;
    }
    else {
        status = open;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer Update:

If your company does not want to push the data out and you are writing an internal application that is only available to employees, then you don't want to use Fusion Tables. The data in Fusion Tables is generally available to the public and is published one of two ways:

[image]

---

### Follow-up To Your May 25, 2012 Comment (if you decide to move forward with FusionTables):

With your comments, I understand better what you are doing. I believe the code you have in the `loadTexas` function that is calling the `styleLayer` function to create the `FusionTablesStyle` objects is correct.

The part that looks suspicious is the ordering of the code in the `loadTexas` function and the `loadFusionLayer` function. There is also a missing `var where` declaration in the `loadFusionLayer` function. I don't think it is causing a problem (at least not in the code you have shown), but it does inadvertently create a global, so corrected that problem in the code that follows. I suggest making the following changes:

1. Create a new `var fusionTablesOptions` in the global space and use `fusionTablesOptions` to set up *all* of the options for the `ftLayer` `FusionTablesLayer`.
2. Change the declaration of `var ftLayer` so that it is assigned to: `null`.
3. Iterate the `aryCounty` array, build the `styles` array, and assign it to the `fusionTablesOptions.styles` property.
4. Assign `fusionTablesOptions.map` to the existing instance of `google.maps.Map` named: `map` (and remove this line of code in the `loadTexas` function: `ftLayer.setMap(map);`).
5. Assign `fusionTablesOptions.query` to the object that is built in the `loadFusionLayer` function.
6. Now that all of the necessary `fusionTablesOptions` properties have been set, create a new instance of `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer`, passing `fusionTablesOptions` to the constructor function.

---

```
var styles = new Array();
//Step 1:
var fusionTablesOptions = {};
//Step 2:
var ftLayer = null;
    
function loadTexas() {
    //Step 3:       
    for (var i = 0; i < aryCounty.length; i++) {
        //Call to the styleLayer function not shown to reduce code size
    }
    fusionTablesOptions.styles = styles;
    //Step 4:
    fusionTablesOptions.map = map;
    loadFusionLayer('TX');
}
    
function loadFusionLayer(state) {    
    var where = null;    //Corrects the missing var keyword
    if (state != null) {
        where = "'State Abbr.' IN ('" + state + "')";
    }
    
    var select = "geometry, 'State Abbr.', 'County Name'";
    //Step 5:
    fusionTablesOptions.query : {            
        select: select,            
        from: countyTableId,            
        where: where
    }
    //Step 6:
    ftLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer( fusionTablesOptions );
}
```

Apologies for the **large answer**, but I wanted to make sure I conveyed all of my suggestions clearly in a way thought would be easy to review or implement.

Comment: The aryCounty is the array that contains the dollar value for each county.

Comment: What I want it to do is load all of the Texas counties as one layer - which it currently does.  Then I want to loop through the aryCounty - array contains the county name and dollar value - and for each county in the array I want it to apply a style to it. However the styles Fusion Table property can only handle 5 arrays.  The data for the aryCounty is coming from a Cognos report.  Perhaps I will need to sort the aryCounty by dollar value and then do an in statement within the style query???

Comment: Sean thank you for the reply.  I am trying to code this now and I am getting an error in the syntax for    fusionTablesOptions.query : {            
        select: select,            
        from: countyTableId,            
        where: where
    }

Comment: Sean, I found the syntax error - simple.  The code you provide does the exact thing that I have originally.  It layers only the last five counties while ignoring the first 237.  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You really only have 4 styles. You need to get the dollar value for each county into your own Fusion Table. You could download the [US Counties Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw), perhaps only the TX counties and create a new FT.  Then add you own dollar value column.  (A simpler better approach would be to merge your actualValues with the Counties table, but I'm not famiiar with merging table.  You need your actual Values and the State-County key values. The merge should create a new table owned by you)

Then you can create your 4 styles as described in the [Maps FT Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles).

There may be syntax errors here.

```
ftLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: countyTable_with_actualValues_Id },
  styles: [{
    // default color
    where: "'State Abbr.' ='" + state + "'";
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: open
    }
  }, {
    where: "'State Abbr.' ='" + state + "' AND actualValue >= " + maxValue;
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: stop
    }
  }, {
    where:  "'State Abbr.' ='" + state + "' AND actualValue >= " + minValue + "AND actualValue < " + midValue;
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: watch
    },
   // Final condition left as an exercise :-)
  }]
});

ftLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was kind of afraid of that.  The company that I am at does not want to push this data out.  And the Google County Fusion Table was the only place that I could find good and easy to use county borders.  Would you or anyone happen to know of a better way of dong this?  Perhaps a different method that may not be FusionTable based?

Comment: Seems like you were planning to load the the data into Javascript any way and thus it would have been readable by the world.

Comment: Somewhat true.  It is for an internal application thus the world would be limited to employees or such.